# count sequences of numbers in a dataframe column using a for loop R

Tags: r, dataframe, for-loop, counter

I want to count the number of times a sequence of numbers occur in R this case say 1 and then 2 (1 and 2 in sequence), trying to use a for loop.

```
set.seed(123)
df<-as.data.frame(replicate(1,sample(0:2,50,rep=TRUE)))
> df
   V1
1   2
2   2
3   2
4   1
5   2
6   1
7   1
8   1
```

...

```
counter = 0
for(i in seq_along(var1$df)){
  if(i == 1 & i + 1 == 2){
        counter = counter + 1
  }
}

counter
```

Basically, I'm trying to calculate the number of times the sequence occurs in a column. I like the idea of a for loop (for learning sake) but am open to other ways. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This  can be achieved without a `for` loop

```
f1 <-function(vec, val){
        rl <- rle(vec)
        sum(rl$values[-length(rl$values)] == val[1] & rl$values[-1] == val[2])
   }

f1(df$V1, 1:2)
#[1] 1
```

---

or using `rleid`

```
library(dplyr)
library(data.table)
df %>% 
    group_by(grp = rleid(V1), V1) %>% 
    slice(1) %>% 
    ungroup %>% 
    mutate(V2 = lead(V1, default = last(V1))) %>%
    summarise(n = sum(V1 == 1 & V2 == 2))
```

---

Or another option is to `paste` the elements together and get the count with `str_count`

```
library(stringr)
str_count(str_c(df$V1, collapse=""), "12")
#[1] 1
```

---

Also, using a `for` loop

```
counter  <- 0
    for(i in seq_len(nrow(df)-1)) {
      if(df$V1[i] == 1 & df$V1[i+1] == 2) {
         counter <- counter + 1
        }

    }
counter
#[1] 1
```

#### data

```
df <- structure(list(V1 = c(2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L)), 
  class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", 
"2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8"))
```

Comment: Thank you @akrun, I edited the question a little--rle works, but for the the run of the sequence 1&2 together is what I meant..

Comment: Thank you @akrun this is all very helpful.